# WikiRank Search

Tags: search-engine

I am making a new concept in searching, I am calling lt as WikiRank, 
In this , a extension will be installed on firefox browser. This extension will see watch the user activity, and he will send visiting url and its visit time also user can give ranking to the material also. So in nutshell,. there will not be any change in user interface, User will use his search any engine but we will collect all of searched website.
So, soon I will be having data such as, How many hour the world has spent on a particular idea and combined user rank.
This database will be useful for getting better search result. 
How can i make this website?
Is the idea is good or unique?
How can I prevent bots or AI agent to give false rank ? May be one captcha at the end of submission of all links ???

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're re-inventing a wheel... again. Did you check any [prior art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexa_Internet) (there are more obviously) on what you're planning to do? From your description it does not sound like a 'new' concept to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly I want to collect page visit time per url of user. Also user can send optional rank (1-10) about the content of the page.